# If $x+\frac{1}{y}=y+\frac{1}{z}=z+\frac{1}{x}$, then prove $x= y= z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $$x+\frac{1}{y}=y+\frac{1}{z}=z+\frac{1}{x}$$ then prove $$x= y= z$$

I cannot solve this problem. Please help me out. This is from ratio and proportion example.

Comment: $x = y + 1/z - 1/y$, now substitute.

Comment: I would start by multiplying with $xyz$ to remove the fractions.

Comment: @ArnaudD. we can't assume that $x \le y \le z$.

Comment: @Santiago [WLOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) means you rename the variables if necessary — here, we have three variables, and we just sort them, calling $x$ the smallest one and $z$ the largest one.

Comment: @Lynn But the expressions are not symmetric, so we must consider two orderings, $x \leqslant y \leqslant z$ and $x \leqslant z \leqslant y$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, of course, sorry. Good point!

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh yes, I should have been more careful. Sorry about that.

Comment: Let me then correct my hint. Assume WLOG that $x$ is the smallest of your three numbers. What happens if $x<z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x+\frac{1}{y}=y+\frac{1}{z}$

$xyz+z=y^2z+y$    (1)

$y+\frac{1}{z}+z+\frac{1}{x}$

$xuy+x=z^2x+z$  (2)

$x+\frac{1}{y}=z+\frac{1}{x}$

$xyz+y=x^2y+x$   (3)

add equations (1),(2)&(3)

$3xyz=x^2y+z^2x+y^2z$

so,   $x=y=z$

Comment: How do you show the last implication?

Comment: Divide by $xyz$ and denote $a = x/z$, $b = z /y$. Now our equality takes form $3 = a + b + 1/(ab)$. If $a, b$ are positive, we can use the AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=1, \;y=-\frac{1}{2},\; z=-2$.

Then $x+\frac{1}{y}=y+\frac{1}{z}=z+\frac{1}{x}=-1$, so the assertion as stated is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assume WLOG that $x$ is the smallest of your three numbers.

Now suppose that $x<z$. Then
$$x+\frac{1}{y}<z+\frac{1}{y}\leq z+\frac{1}{x},$$which is a contradiction; hence $x=z$, and together with your second equality, this implies that $z=y$.

Comment: This seems like the simplest argument, assuming all the numbers are positive.

Comment: Yes I (unconsciously) assumed this, and so does the other answer. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote?