# Find all real solutions for the system: $x+\frac{1}{y}=y+\frac{1}{z}=z+\frac{1}{x}$ given that $xyz=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Find all real solutions for the system:
>   $$x+\frac{1}{y}=y+\frac{1}{z}=z+\frac{1}{x}$$ 
>   given that $xyz=1$.

This is from a math olympiad (OBM 2009).

By inspection it is easy to spot that a possible solution is $x=y=z=1$ but are there others? It looks like it is not a difficult question but I'm not finding a nice approach.

Hints and solutions are appreciated. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

**Edit 1:** Pointed out by helpful comments below, [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2078159/460565) presents a complete solution for this problem, for all possible cases. From that mentioned answer we can conclude that when $xyz=1$ there are two possible solutions:

$$(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)~~\text{and}~~(x,y,z)=(a,\frac{-1}{a+1},\frac{-(a+1)}{a}),\forall a \in \mathbb R\setminus\{0;-1\}.$$

Answers using other techniques or arguments are welcomed.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078126/x-frac1y-y-frac1z-z-frac1x-then-value-of-xyz-is and the linked one : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062159/if-x-frac1y-y-frac1z-z-frac1x-then-prove-x-y-z

Comment: $x=1, y=-\frac{1}{2}, z=-2$ works

Comment: $x=x, y = -\frac1{x+1}, z = -\frac{x+1}x$  also works.